# How to activate conda environments while still being able to change the environment with eval --setenvironment

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda

I have a working environment in which I need to often change from one python conda environment to other environments provided by colleagues to run code. 
In order to have the conda environments active when I work, I have the following code in my .bashrc:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/soft/cdtng/tools/anaconda/3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' '$
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/soft/cdtng/tools/anaconda/3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/soft/cdtng/tools/anaconda/3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/soft/cdtng/tools/anaconda/3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup

# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

The problem is that with this setup, when some colleague asks me to, for instance, run

```
eval $(anaconda --version 3.1_tf_cpu --setenvironment)
```

Then I get the error message:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

And the execution does not work. What I would need is:

- keep on being able to work on my conda environments (when I start a shell, I always get the (base) as default. This is not a requirement, but I want that when I do "conda activate myenv" then myenv does get active in the shell)
- but I need to still be able to use the above setenvironment command and manage it to be effective.

Sorry if the question is too basic, but I am not so expert on managing conda environments.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in another post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default

Feel free to erase this post in case it might be an unwanted repetition.

My conda set up in the .bashrc looks as follows now:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/soft/cdtng/tools/anaconda/3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/soft/cdtng/tools/anaconda/3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/soft/cdtng/tools/anaconda/3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/soft/cdtng/tools/anaconda/3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup

#CONDA_AUTO_ACTIVATE_BASE=false
conda config --set auto_activate_base false

# <<< conda initialize <<<
```