# Changing conda environment for python commands

Tags: python, environment, conda

I wrote a Python script which uses a package named `paraview`. I installed this package to my environment. I want that whenever the code is run, the environment must be changed and then the code is run.

I added the following command at the beginning of the code but it didn't work.

```python
import os
os.system("conda activate <env. name>")
```

I get following error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.

To initialize your shell, run
$ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
```

I tried the solution given at [How to activate conda environments while still being able to change the environment with eval --setenvironment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192331/how-to-activate-conda-environments-while-still-being-able-to-change-the-environm) but couldn't get any result.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you run `conda init <shell_name>`?

Comment: Yes, I run that. It gives; No action taken.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```py
import os
os.system("conda activate <env. name>")
```

Use `source activate` instead of `conda activate`.